# getGlobalVisibleRect of current visible screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to get the global coordinates of the current whole screen, not of a particular view in my fragment. I want to display an enlarged profile picture when a user clicks on its thumbnail. How do I do that?

This is the function I am using-

```
 final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
 final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
 final Point globalOffset = new Point();
 getView().getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
```

But I want the picture to be enlarged taking the whole visible screen, not in the center of any provided view..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set onclick listener for image view and add a popup window to show an image. It will provide a full-screen image view.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              // Code to show image in full screen:
              new PhotoFullPopupWindow(context, R.layout.popup_photo_full, view, URL, null);

          }
      });
```

you can find all the data about this when u nevigate http://www.tutorialsface.com/2017/10/whatsapp-like-full-screen-imageview-android-with-zoom-blur-bg-in-popup-window-example-tutorial/ tutorial.

Comment: You just saved my day!! I was trying a bit complicated method, this is way better and more manageable. Thank You!!

Comment: Nice to hear it. @BittenTech Please upvote and accept this answer if it is helpful